# What are the best penetration testing Linux distributions?

Tags: linux, security, testing, security-testing

what are the best Linux operating systems that is use to security testing and hacking ?
I heard Black track is the best.What are other best OS in the industry and what kind of differences in those OS ?

Answer (score 1):

its BackTrack Linux, i guess a newer version of it is called 'Kali Linux'

Answer (score 0):

@OldMonk is dead on, BackTrack & Kali are great. 
Checkout Pentoo http://www.pentoo.ch/ is another one out there..